# Java Application taking long time to execute Groovy scripts which are precomplied

Tags: groovy

I have my groovy script precomplied on server start (I have stored groovy scripts as varchar in DB) up like below in Map ,

```
final Binding sharedData = new Binding();
final GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(sharedData);
script= shell.parse(rs.getString("VALIDATION_SCRIPT"));
```

Now when checking the validation on input records based on specified validation id i try to  execute the precompiled script as below.

```
Script scrpt = Validation.getScript(); //getting from cache
scrpt.getBinding().setVariable("attributes", objects);
scrpt.getBinding().setVariable("tools", scrpt);
GroovyResponse gr = scrpt.evaluate("tools.valid(attributes)");
```

but here my application takes long time to evaluate..i guess heap size also gets increase and GC takes place. Can any one help me if there are better way to do it. with out impacting the performance.

one of My groovy script :

```
import com.fis.derivatives.utility.generic.model.GroovyResponse;

def valid(Map mapInput){
    GroovyResponse obj = new GroovyResponse()
    if(mapInput.inputVal.equals("1")){
        obj.setStatus(true) ;
        obj.setResultValue("B") ;
    } else if(mapInput.inputVal.equals("2")){
        obj.setStatus(true) ;
        obj.setResultValue("S") ;
    }else{
        obj.setStatus(false);
        obj.setComment("Error : Unable to extract BUY_SELL. Please check BS value "+mapInput.inputVal+".")
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: maybe the problem in script? could you share it? also the following line is strange : `scrpt.getBinding().setVariable("tools", scrpt);` you passing into script a reference to this script... here you could have stack overflow.

Comment: previously i was doing ..Binding binding = new Binding(); GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding); binding.setVariable("attributes", objects);
  binding.setVariable("tools", scrpt);
shell.evaluate("tools.valid(attributes)");                              groovy file  is in another comment

Comment: import com.fis.derivatives.utility.generic.model.GroovyResponse;
def valid(Map mapInput)
{GroovyResponse obj = new GroovyResponse()
if(mapInput.inputVal.equals("1")){
obj.setStatus(true) ;
obj.setResultValue("B") ;
} else if(mapInput.inputVal.equals("2")){
obj.setStatus(true) ;
obj.setResultValue("S") ;
}else{
obj.setStatus(false);
obj.setComment("Error : Unable to extract BUY_SELL. Please check BS value "+mapInput.inputVal+".")
}return obj;
}

Comment: Please put this into your question.

Comment: done. Please help :(

Comment: what's inside of `Validation.getScript()` ? how get from  cache could be without any key?

Comment: I have maintain one pojo in which i have map of validation key & validation object(object will have Script object). Is my complinig way correct? i just used parse method and store Script in pojo object. is there any better way to have a precomiled script and than invokeMethod on it during runtime ?

Comment: again: i don't see `key` parameter to your `getScript()` method. and as you said cache - is a key-to-script mapping in your case. so i expect to see something like: `getScript("MY_VALIDATION_RULE")` another point: i prefer to store in cache map the class and not an instance like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53957449/groovy-shell-script-object-not-executed-entirely/53959727#53959727) - this allows to run the same compiled script in multiple threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - I have doubts about your cache. getting from cache without any key is strange...

```
Script scrpt = Validation.getScript(); //getting from cache
```

2 - rework a little the call of groovy:

```
Script scrpt = Validation.getScript(); //getting from cache
//we will pass attributes as a parameter to method
//scrpt.getBinding().setVariable("attributes", objects); 
//not necessary to pass to script link to itself 
//scrpt.getBinding().setVariable("tools", scrpt);

GroovyResponse gr = scrpt.invokeMethod​("valid", objects);
```